# How to globally override properties of a 3rd party component in VueJS

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I am using a component from a library which provides properties to set some texts:

```
props: {
    placeholder: { type: String, default: "Select something" },
    // ... More text properties here
}
```

Usage

```
// Shows "Select something" when no value selected
<vue-multiselect></vue-multiselect>

// To show something else, you can specify the prop
<vue-multiselect placeholder="Another message here"></vue-multiselect>
```

All across the application we will be using the same texts, and of course, we would like to avoid repeating it everywhere.

```
// Shows "This is the default text" when no value selected
<vue-multiselect></vue-multiselect>
```

Given that we have no control on the component, how can we set those property defaults globally?

Vue plugin? Vue directive?

I am quite ok with most basic vue concepts (custom components, events, binding, etc.) but as I don't know plugins and directives I am stuck on that one.

Comment: [`extend`](https://vuejs.org/v2/api/#Vue-extend) the component to make a customized version. (Each component is a Vue instance, so you can `extend` the component, and not just the base Vue instance.)

Comment: Create a wrapper component. A [functional component](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/render-function.html#Functional-Components) is even better as it could act as a lightweight transparent wrapper.